# Typescript arrow notation clumsy, alternative?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I feel like i'm doing passing functions wrong in typescript.
I always end up writing something like:

```
var somefunc = (p1, p2, p3, p4) => { thatfunc(p1,p2,p3,p4) };
```

where in plain javascript i would just do:

```
var somefunc = thatfunc;
```

with longer parameter names this gets so incredible clumsy and longish to write so I was wondering if there is a better alternative.

Example:

```
class A {
  public foo = "bar";

  public thatfunc(x, y, z) {
    console.log(this.foo);
  }
}

class B {
  var somefunc;
  var a;
  constructor() {
    this.a = new A();
    this.somefunc = this.a.thatfunc
  }
}

var b = new B();
b.somefunc("x", "y", "z")  //will error undefined foo

class B {
  var somefunc;
  var a;
  constructor() {
    this.a = new A();
    this.somefunc = (x, y ,z) => { this.a.thatfunc(x,y,z) }
  }
}

var b = new B();
b.somefunc("x", "y", "z") // will work displays "bar"
```

Comment: Surely you can do that simple assignment in TypeScript too.

Comment: TypeScript is just "annotated JS". You can still write "plain JS" in TypeScript.

Comment: @Pointy I know, but then i keep getting undefined errors

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Sure, but i'm asking for a typescript way

Comment: Well maybe you should ask a direct question about those errors.

Comment: @Pointy I bet everyone programming in typescript knows the problem with this.foo being undefined in callbacks and such, thats why we use arrow notation in the first place

Comment: I think you should change your pattern. Why not use inheritance?

Comment: @DavidSherret that was just as an example, i'm asking for a general approach to the passing callbacks and functions problem with this context in typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this.somefunc = this.a.thatfunc

Simply:

```
this.somefunc = this.a.thatfunc.bind(this.a);
```

Alternatively:

```
public thatfunc = (x, y, z) => {
  console.log(this.foo);
}
```

> where in plain javascript i would just do:

Not true. In this case TypeScript *is* JavaScript.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Was looking for the alternative notation, now i can happily: somefunc = thatfunc;